# Centralized workflow, is rebase a good idea to avoid the merge commits ?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

We are about to start using Git and i have a question regarding the workflow.

We will have a central Git Repository. If we assume a very simple scenario. Devs make changes in their own repo then commit locally. At the same time other does the same and eventually someone will Push to the origin. Everything fine. Now one of the other devs Pulls changes which merges the changes they made and when they push to the server we will have a merge commit, not so nice history wise but ok.

I read that rebase can solve this problem but one has to be careful about rebase and this is where i fail in my understanding what that problem is if we use a Centralized server or maybe there are no problems. Could somebody explain ?

/donnib

Comment: Once have look may help you http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/10/git-team-workflows-merge-or-rebase/

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to rebase until you learn what git can do.  rebase is powerful but causes problems for people who are still thinking the way subversion wants them to think.  For now, just merge.  It's still easier than SVN merges.  And soon, your workflow will adapt, and rebases will become possible.